# SharePoint Blog: ViewPost.aspx Doesn't work, But, Post.aspx - Any fix?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my **SharePoint Online**, I have a one single site collection with two languages, and I am using the Blog Posts in both languages. When I search for something, the result will be:

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Intra/subsite/de/nuws/Lists/msgs/ViewPost.aspx?ID=10 => This does NOT work, and it redirects to 404 The page you're looking for doesn't exist.!

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Intra/subsite/de/nuws/Lists/msgs/Post.aspx?ID=10 => This works, But, Of course I am manually removing the "View" from the URL !

How can I fix this issue so that the displayed results shows the correct URL ?

BTW, When I search about posts which are in the other languages, It finds them and when I click on them, they open correctly !

Answer (score 0):

The way to correct is is to update the contenttype which can be done with the following powershell:

```
param($blogweb, $blogListName = "Blogmeddelelser")

$web = get-spweb $blogweb

$list = $web.Lists[$blogListName]

$ct = $list.ContentTypes["Post"]
$ct.DisplayFormUrl = "Lists/$blogListName/Post.aspx"
$ct.Update()
```

Check the same Scenario that match your issue at : [SharePoint Blog Post redirect fails with 404](http://wp.sjkp.dk/sharepoint-blog-post-redirect-fails-with-404/)

Comment: M.Qassas, I seen this article before I post, It is not really what I am encountering. My issue is only that I have the "View" from the URL and causing the issue

Comment: but with other language it's working ?! as you said ? should you elaborate more please